# using regex to find a specific word

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

I want to find the word "circle" and "circles" in the list.

```
list = {"circle" , "picircle" , "circles" }
```

The regex code I wrote which isn't working:

```
StringCases[#, 
RegularExpression["(/\\b)(\\w*circle\\w*)(\\b//g)"]] & /@ list
```

The output I want:

```
{{circle},{},{circles}}
```

The output I get:

```
{{},{},{}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logic of you regular expression is not entirely clear to me.

Mathematica's `RegularExpression` does not need any delimiters and I don't think that there is a "global" switch. In any case, the following matches all single words "circle", "circles", "Circle" and "Circles":

```
list = {"circle", "picircle", "circles", "Circle"};
StringCases[#, RegularExpression["\\b[Cc]ircles?\\b"]] & /@ list
(* {{"circle"}, {}, {"circles"}, {"Circle"}} *)
```

Comment: how can I can change this so that it can be used for "Circles" as well?

Comment: @Aryan I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {"circle", "picircle", "circles"};
StringCases[#, 
   StartOfString ~~ "circle" | "circles" ~~ EndOfString] & /@ list
StringCases[#, RegularExpression["^(circle|circles)$"]] & /@ list
```

Comment: your solution works! i upvoted it, but I wanted it in RegEx, hence couldn't verify it as the answer :)